# Adding an externally linked button to a single product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization

I have tried the coding offered in the other related questions but they are not working - possibly because I'm not good at this.
I want to add a button to only one product alongside the 'add to cart' button that will link to an external website. This must appear on the shop page and the product description page because I don't want international buyers to 'add to cart' without knowing they have an international option that saves on delivery.
Just a heads up - I am not a developer but can navigate in code with direction... please help this lost soul

Comment: For shipping you can just tweek your shipping zones taxes etc for international. Dont know your final goal but sounds more clean over some button. The example below would do the trick but still you may want to mention is it premium theme and do you have child theme ? In case you dont have child theme next time you update your changes will be lost keep that in mind.

Comment: Hi. Thank you Martin. Unfortunately, shipping is extremely expensive for international buyers so I will prefer they buy off amazon. I did try and the rate is more than the actual book price. I have a paid theme - 907 Watch Shop Theme. I'm not sure what a child theme is. I think mine might be a child theme because 907 has a number of templates and I chose one of them. Is this correct?

Comment: In the documentation of your theme should have instructions how to install child theme. From what i see they have child theme. Child theme is using your parent theme files but in case you want to override something you place the code there. If the theme have update will update only the parent files not the child ones. That way you wont need to add any custom code over again. Read more here(https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code help you to add the external link button.
copy the code and add to your theme function.php file.
its work only with product id 41 and 53 in my example you can replace with your product id in which you wants to show this button.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_single_product_button', 20); // add button in single product page
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'additional_single_product_button', 20); // add button in shop page
function additional_single_product_button()
{
   global $product;

   // Define your targeted product IDs in the array below 
   $targeted_product_ids = array(41, 53);

   if (in_array($product->get_id(), $targeted_product_ids)) {
       echo '<br><a  href="https://google.com" class="button">i am external button</a>'; // your button
    }
}
```

i wish it help you to fix the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. I'm not sure where to find the function.php file. I'll youtube how to do that! :) I really appreciate your help!